# How to access Response cookies in angular2?

Tags: http, angular, cookies, ionic2

I'm trying to access this cookies (the response ones):
[image]

When I open the request in the chrome debug tools in the network section I can clearly see that the cookies are present, but how can I access those values from my code? I've never worked with cookies before and I don't know what to do to "extract" them... I'm working on a Ionic2 project using Http.

I've read that the `allowCredentials: true` header has to be sent but that didn't work...

### Here's the request/response details:

[image]

### Here's the service:

```
public callLogin(service_guid: string, pos_guid: string, login_data: Object) {

        return this.http.post(
            this.url + service_guid + "/" + pos_guid + "/ack", 
            login_data,
            {withCredentials: true}
            )
            .map(response => response.headers);
    }
```

### And the caller:

```
this.__posService.callLogin(login_data.service_guid, login_data.pos_guid, {"password": data.password})
                            .subscribe(
                                res => {
                                    console.log("Success:");
                                    console.log(res.get("apsession"); // this returns undefined
                                },
                                err => {
                                    console.log("Error:");
                                }
                            );
```

When I try to access the cookie from the header it returns **undefined**. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The name of the response header you are trying to get is actually Set-Cookie not apsession. So if you did something like `res.get("set-cookie")` it would return the first header that matched that name. Since you have more than 1, you could do:

```
let headers: Headers = res.headers;
headers.getAll('set-cookie');
```

which returns a list of all headers with that name. You could find apsession in there probably.

See:

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/Headers-class.html
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/headers
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the tip! But now when I try to get the cookies that way I get an empty array as result: "[ ]".